Shiny modules - including module CSS and JS without repeating
I'm wondering what are the ways to include some CSS and possibly Javascript that's needed for a Shiny module to work, without duplicating that code when multiple instances of the module are called? For example, say I have a module with this UI:
my_module_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "special_button.css")
    ),
    actionButton(ns("button"), class = "special-button")
  )
}

my_module_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
    # Server-side functionality
   }
  )
}
      

This would work for styling the button appropriately. However, If I were to reuse this module at multiple times in the main app, the special_button.css stylesheet would be added multiple times. If I were to use inline CSS, the specific rules would be multiplied for every button instance.
Is there a way to provide these stylesheets as a singleton, while still keeping it a part of the module definition? I'd like to have everything related to the module kept inside the module, instead of providing JS and CSS in the main app.

You  could set a flag (in, say, session$userData) and get the module to check if the flag is set.  If it is, do nothing.  If it isn't, include the necessary singletons and set the flag.

You can wrap the link tag in htmltools::singleton:
my_module_UI <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(
        tags$head(
            htmltools::singleton(
                tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "special_button.css")
            )
        ),
        actionButton(ns("button"), label = "button", class = "special-button")
    )
}


That's a much neater idea than my suggestion in comments.  I didn't know about htmltools::singleton().  I learn something new every day!  Thank you.

@Limey you're welcome! I actually thought of the flag solution as well, but then I remembered stumbling upon this somewhat "unknown" function some time ago :)

This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much.
